# Unable to boot iOS simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, osx-yosemite

I am using MAC OSX YOSEMITE 10.10.3 with Xcode 6.3.2 configuration.
When i am going to run app on iOS simulator, it shows me unable to boot iOS simulator.But with device it works fine.
Can any one help me here, I had tried so many thing as googled. But not getting any solution.
Reinstalled Xcode 2 times also.